# Returning a string stream (char*)

Tags: c++, char, ostringstream

My professor wants me to output the "area" from calculateArea as a char/string. I'm not sure exactly what he means, but maybe some of you might understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char& calculateArea(double diameter, double chord)
{   
    double length_1, length_2, angle; //This creates variables used by the formula.
    angle = acos( (0.5 * chord) / (0.5 * diameter) ); //This calculates the angle, theta, in radians.
    
    cout << "Angle: " << (angle * 180) / 3.14159 << "\n"; //This code displays the angle, currently in radians, in degrees.
    
    length_1 = (sin(angle)) * 6; //This finds the side of the triangle, x.
    
    cout << "X: " << length_1 << " inches "<< "\n"; //This code displays the length of 'x'.
    
    length_2 = (0.5 * diameter) - length_1; /*This code finds the length of 'h', by subtracting 'x' from the radius (which is half                                              the diameter).*/
    
    cout << "h: " << length_2 << " inches" << "\n"; //This code displays the length of 'h'.
    
    double area = ((2.0/3.0) * (chord * length_2)) + ( (pow(length_2, 3) / (2 * chord) ) ); /*This code calculates the area of the                                                                                                            slice.*/
    ostringstream oss;
    
    oss << "The area is: "<< area << " inches";
    
    string aStr = oss.str();
    
    cout << "Debug: "<< aStr.c_str() << "\n";
    
    const char *tStr = aStr.c_str();
    
    cout << "Debug: " << tStr << "\n";
    
    return *tStr;
    
    //This returns the area as a double.

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    double dia, cho; //Variables to store the user's input.
    
    cout << "What is your diameter? ";  //
    cin >> dia;                          // This code asks the user to input the diameter & chord. The function will calculate
    cout << "What is your chord? ";      // the area of the slice.
    cin >> cho;                          //
    
    const char AreaPrint = calculateArea(dia, cho); //Sends the input to the function.
    
    cout << AreaPrint; //Prints out the area.
            
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output as this though:

> What is your diameter? 12
>
> What is your chord? 10
>
> Angle: 33.5573
>
> X: 3.31662 inches
>
> h: 2.68338 inches
>
> Debug: The area is: 18.8553 inches
>
> Debug: The area is: 18.8553 inches
>
> T

I need to figure out how to return the string tStr points to. If you don't get what I'm saying, sorry, not really sure what the professor is asking for.

Comment: Why not just return the string itself?

Comment: Are you sure he asks for returning a string? I guess I would want to return a `double` from the function and print e.g. in the `main()` function.

Comment: Yeah, I figured how to do that (double, and returning a string). Returning the string and all, but when he assigned it, there was something about const char *. So, I'm assuming he wanted something like that.

Comment: You are returning reference to a local variable. Very, very bad idea.

Comment: Hmm, so perhaps you should ask your professor to post the question here? ... How do you expect us to know what your professor wants if not even you do understand it?

Comment: He wants us to return the area as a char. Is the way I'm doing it right?

Comment: @jon It makes no sense to return it as a `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returing a char reference not a string.
(the *tStr says 'give me the contents of the pointer')

A more correct version of what you are trying is:

```
const char* calculateArea(double diameter, double chord)
```

and

```
return tStr; // no 'content of'
```

But this is still bad: the string returned is "out of scope" when aStr goes out of scope, so you really need to return a copy of the characters or just return the string itself (and let the std lib worry about the copy for you)

```
const string calculateArea(double diameter, double chord)
```

...

```
return aStr;
```

Comment: Yeah, but any idea what he would have meant by const char*?

Comment: You can return const char*, but you need to have aStr static (so it does not get destroyed) or copy it's characters. I guess it all depends on what you are supposed to be learning pointers or objects. Returning a string is the easiest approach. If you want to copy the string, just strcpy() tStr - but then you need to worry about who owns the memory (in a real program this could cause a memory leak)

Comment: I'll double check and come back to this on Wednesday. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: And this works (the first part). It seems to work, without an out of scope error.

Comment: It may seem to work, but you actually have a "dangling pointer" (a pointer to unallocated memory. It will probably work forever in a small program like this, but if the program got bigger or you called more stuff before you tried to use the result, you might get a nasty surprise.

Comment: So far, all I'm required to do is give the user the ability to input a circumference and chord, and it calculates the area. Nothing too serious yet. I just started the class. But thanks for your help! It means a lot.

Comment: return 'const string'? why do you need const there?